# Cannot see PXGraph template in visual studio even after Deploy Acumatica Framework Tools

Tags: acumatica

I am not able to find PXGraph template for customization in visual studio even after I Deploy Acumatica Framework Tools.

I am running:

Acumatica Framework Version 18.201.0050.

MS VS 2017 Version 15.8.7

Can anyone Help me how to add the template?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  I was forced to manually copy the items in the Acumatica template into the default directory for Visual Studio.  To learn how to view the default directory, see this link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-locate-and-organize-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2017

Comment: Note that inside Visual Studio the templates will be available only for ASP project type.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions gentlemen